# postgresql replace function using pattern matching characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having a table named "OptionsDetail" with column named "URL" in postgresql database.  The "URL" column contain the following data

### URL

```
http://www.site1.com/ebw/file1/detail.action?cid=1
http://www.another2.com/ebw/file1/detail.action?cid=11&code=MYCODE
http://www.anothersite3.com/ebw/file1/detail.action?cid=12&code=ANOTHERCODE&option=ROOM
```

Now I want to replace the data in URL to

### URL

```
/file1/detail.action?cid=1
/file1/detail.action?cid=11&code=MYCODE
/file1/detail.action?cid=12&code=ANOTHERCODE&menu=ROOM
```

I wrote the following query to perform the above functionality

```
 UPDATE  "OptionsDetail" SET "URL" = replace("URL",'http://%/ebw/file1','/file1') WHERE  "URL" LIKE  '%/ebw/file1%';
```

And also another way I wrote like this

```
  UPDATE  "OptionsDetail" SET "URL" = replace("URL",'%/ebw/file1','/file1') WHERE  "URL" LIKE  '%/ebw/file1%';
```

Query is executing successfully saying like for ex: 200 rows affected but "URL" column data is not changing the way I need, the data is remaining as it is.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: `replace` doesn't support wildcards. You want `regexp_replace`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `replace` doesn't support wildcards like `%`:

```
replace("URL",'http://%/ebw/file1','/file1')
                     ^^^
```

You can use [`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) instead:

```
UPDATE  YourTable
SET     URL = regexp_replace(URL, 'http://.*/ebw/file1', '/file1') 
WHERE   URL LIKE '%/ebw/file1%'
```

Note that `regexp_replace` uses different wildcards than `like`.  In regular expressions, "Any number of any character" is `.*` instead of `%`.

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a70da/1/0)

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if you use `%` instead of `.` in `regexp_replace`, it acts as a non-capturing wildcard character, so anything that it matches won't be replaced.